# What is Clara's status now?

Tags: doctor-who

In *Face the Raven*,

> Clara Oswald was supposed to die, but instead got pulled out of her time stream and ended up traveling with Me.

In *Twice Upon a Time*,

> we see that the Testimony has her memories.

Does this mean she

> has now died?

Or would

> they have gotten to her before her time stream became frozen?

---

<sub>I have seen every New Who episode, even if it has been some time, so spoilers are fine in answers.</sub>

Comment: "Now" is meaningless. Somewhere in time, Clara and Me are adventuring in their stolen TARDIS. Somewhere in time, presumably, those adventures are complete, and Clara has returned to Gallifrey to complete her death. The Testimony may have harvested her memories at that point.

Comment: @Politank-Z Or shortly before the Raven was supposed to take her. I don't think it matters much.

Comment: Still no pulse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that...

> ...the "memory" of Clara includes the knowledge that the Doctor had forgotten her, it's safe to say that it was taken at some point after she and Me left in their Tardis. Presumable once she returned to Gallifrey the long way round.

Of course, wibbly wobbly, timey wimey: that doesn't mean the Doctor can't run into her or anyone else in there every again. Indeed, recall the circumstances of his first meeting with River. These things can happen out of order.

Answer (score 2):

Clara is basically dead. In [Hell Bent](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Hell_Bent_(TV_story)) the Doctor takes her in the moment before her death and escapes in a stolen TARDIS. However, Clara no longer has a pulse. The Doctor then runs into Me at the end of universe (which he assumed would free Clara). Me chastises the Doctor for trying to save Clara from her fate.

The Doctor tries to erase Clara's memories of him, to at least let her lead a new life somewhere else, but Clara reversed the process and The Doctor had his memories of her largely erased. Me and Clara drop The Doctor in Nevada, which is where the episode happens, and he pours out to Clara (not recognizing her) his regret. She leaves him there, with his own TARDIS. Thus we [get to this scene](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/35-12.html) (note that Ashildr is only called Me in this episode)

> ASHILDR: Still no pulse?
>   CLARA: Time isn't healing. I am still frozen.
>   ASHILDR: You know what that means?
>   CLARA: It means my death is a fixed event. The universe depends on it happening.
>   ASHILDR: I'm sorry.
>   CLARA: Why? Why does everybody think I am so scared? We all face the raven in the end. That is the deal. If I go back to Gallifrey, they can put me back, right? On Trap Street, the moment they took me out?
>   ASHILDR: Of course.
>   CLARA: Mind you, seeing as I'm not actually ageing, there's a tiny little bit of wiggle room, isn't there?
>   ASHILDR: Wiggle room?
>   CLARA: Wiggle room. Yeah, you know, wiggle room. We could, er, you know, stop off on the way.
>   (Clara sets coordinates.)
>   ASHILDR: Where are we going?
>   CLARA: Gallifrey. Like I said, Gallifrey. The long way round.
>   (The American Diner whizzes through the Vortex.)

The episode ends with the TARDIS Clara and Me are in going off into the universe.

Answer (score 1):

Stephen Moffat has answered this regarding Nardol but the answer stands for Clara as well. I will find the quote when I have time but he basically said that as Testimony is far in the future at some point Nardol has died, but he may return in the future (depending on the new writers) fully alive and this doesn't retcon that scene.

Clara can be considered to be exactly the same case. Maybe she died soon after we last saw her, maybe something happened and she lived to 100 but at some point she would have died and Testimony will have downloaded her memories.